# How to filter out numbers from text documents

Tags: orange

I have several text files that have numbers in them.  It would be very difficult to filter out all the numbers by creating a Stop Word txt file with every number from 1 to 2010, plus very inefficient use of resources.  Is there a way in Orange to parse out all numbers from text documents?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, orange has regex abilities as seen [here](https://blog.biolab.si/2017/06/19/text-preprocessing/).  If you're unfamiliar with regex here's a link regarding regex with [numbers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html).  The idea is pretty straight forward.  Use regular expression to find all numbers, then replace the numbers with something like a blanks string a placeholder word like "NUMBER".